# alias_attribute and creating and method with the original attribute name causes a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alias-method, alias-method-chain

Im trying to dynamically create a method chain in one attribute in my model.
By now I have this function:

```
def create_filtered_attribute(attribute_name)
          alias_attribute "#{attribute_name}_without_filter", attribute_name

          define_method "#{attribute_name}" do
            filter_words(self.send("#{attribute_name}_without_filter"))
          end
end
```

so I receive a string with the attribute name, alias it for '*_without_filter*' (alias_method or alias_method_chain fails here, because the attribute isnt there when the class is created),
and I create a new method with the attribute name, where I filter its contents.

But somehow, when I call *"#{attribute_name}_without_filter"* it calls my new method (i think because the alias_attribute some how), and the program goes into a stack loop.

Im trying to rename that attribute, so I can use its name for a method...

Can someone please enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between `alias_method` and `alias_attribute`. [alias_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method) actually makes a *copy* of the old method, whereas [alias_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute) just defines new methods, which *call old ones*.

Note, that `model.attribute` and `model.attribute=` methods in ActiveRecord simply call [read_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/read_attribute) and [write_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/write_attribute), so you always can access your attribute, even if you override it's getter or setter:

```
  define_method "#{attribute_name}" do
    filter_words(self.read_attribute(attribute_name))
  end
```

Comment: There is blog post about alias_method  versus alias_attribute and its use case: http://www.chrisrolle.com/blog/aliasing-the-rails-way